# Discrete Mathematics remainder

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Emma has $75$ crowns, all in the $16$ st crown coin (namely in $1$-crown, $5$-crowns, and $10$-crowns).

How many coins of each kind has she?

My solution is to use the Euclidean algorithm:

$75 = 10\cdot7 + 5$.
$10 = 5\cdot2 + 0$.

So I think it is in five $10$-crown coins and in two $5$-crown coins but, in the solution they say solved it with some strange equations.

Comment: What is $16$ st crown coin?

Comment: Please make your question clearer...what is 'int the 1-,5-10-'?What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry the total crowns she has!

Comment: I thought 75 was the total crowns?

Comment: Its the sum of all crowns!

Comment: Five $10$-crown coins and two $5$-crown coins are worth only $60$ crowns, not $75$. What is the $16$? The number of coins that she has? And what is ‘st’? An abbreviation for *standard*?

Comment: The first step is to get the question right.  It sounds like she has $16$ coins with individual values of $1,5,10$ crowns and total value $75$ crowns.  Is that what you are trying to ask?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like she has $16$ coins with individual values of $1,5,10$ crowns and total value $75$ crowns. There is a cute approach here-you can make $75$ crowns out of $15\ 5$ crown coins. Each time you trade two fives for a ten, you reduce the count by $1$.  Each time you trade a five for five ones, you increase the count by $4$.  So increase it once and decrease it three times for a net of plus one.  You wind up with $75=3 \cdot 10 + 8 \cdot 5 + 5 \cdot 1$